# PHP or MySQL is replacing certain string characters with gibberish in echoed output

Tags: php, mysql

I have code for a query that looks like this (yes, I'm aware my input is not sanitized):

```
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE comment LIKE '%".$_POST['search_query']."'%";
```

But for whatever reason when I enter the word 'fake' and I echo it back, it comes out like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE comment LIKE '0.000000ake'
```

I genuinely have no idea what is going on here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're echoing the SQL statement not results from running it?

Comment: How are you echoing this out? I wonder if you're using `sprintf()`, and the `%` is confusing the output.

Comment: I'm guessing a `sprint()` `%f` displaying a float of 0, then the `ake`

Comment: Any js traitment on search query before sending ?

Comment: @developerwjk Well I wasn't getting any results so I echoed to see why not.

Comment: @developerwjk Wow I am a moron. You guys were all correct - it's just a sprintf formatting issue with PHP's echo - MySQL is receiving the correct query.

Comment: @halfer Wow I am a moron. You guys were all correct - it's just a sprintf formatting issue with PHP's echo - MySQL is receiving the correct query.

Comment: @MarkBaker Wow I am a moron. You guys were all correct - it's just a sprintf formatting issue with PHP's echo - MySQL is receiving the correct query.

Comment: @bigben3333 Wow I am a moron. You guys were all correct - it's just a sprintf formatting issue with PHP's echo - MySQL is receiving the correct query.

Comment: You need to use `%%` in the [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) string format in order to get a `%` in the returned string. Or you can pass the `%` as an argument: `sprintf("... LIKE '%s%s%s'", '%', $_POST['search_query'], '%');`. But don't forget to escape the value from `$_POST[]` when you put it into the query: use [`mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['search_query'])`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or better use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

if possible sanitize the input.
Also echo the string with the echo function.
If i have to guess, somehow the %fake% is being printed with a printf or sprintf function (or similar) that is converting the %f into something different.

Comment: You are correct - thanks for your reply. It was simply a sprintf formatting issue, MySQL is indeed receiving the correct query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` 
WHERE comment LIKE '%{$_POST['search_query']}%' ";
```

Two things I changed: I switched the concat to the curly bracket and also your closing quotation was inside the second percentage.

Comment: Thank you for your response - it turns out that it was just a PHP formatting issue; MySQL is receiving the correct query.